# MailMessage class in TYPO3 7.2 How to use it?

Tags: typo3, extbase

In my extension in TYPO3 6.2.x I sent mail through the function.

```
protected function sendMail($senderEmail, $recipientEmail, $subject, $message) {
    $this->view->assign('settings', $this->settings);   
    $mail = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance('TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Mail\\MailMessage');
    $mail->setFrom(array($this->settings['fromEmail']));
    $mail->setTo(array($this->settings['toEmail']));
    $mail->setSubject($this->settings['subject']);
    $mail->setBody(htmlspecialchars_decode($message), 'text/html');
    if($this->settings['debugMail'] == 1) {
        $this->debug($message);
    } else {
        $mail->send();
    }
}
```

It worked good. But in TYPO3 7.2 it's not working. How to use it?

Comment: Are you getting an error message?

Comment: No errors. No mails in mailbox. If I try send test mail from Install Tool - it works, from powermail - works. If I try

Comment: send test mail like https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/ApiOverview/Mail/Index.html - nothing. I tried smtp and mail settings in Install Tool

Comment: Try the mbox setting to test whether the generation of the mail or the sending is the problem. BTW, 7.2 is out of support, please upgrade at least to 7.6 LTS.

Answer (score 4):

Try this, it's work for me[7.6.0]. might help you.

```
/**
* @param array $recipient recipient of the email in the format array('recipient@domain.tld' => 'Recipient Name')
* @param array $sender sender of the email in the format array('sender@domain.tld' => 'Sender Name')
* @param string $subject subject of the email
* @param string $templateName template name (UpperCamelCase)
* @param array $variables variables to be passed to the Fluid view
* @return boolean TRUE on success, otherwise false
*/
protected function sendTemplateEmail(array $recipient, array $sender, $subject, $templateName, array $variables = array(), $attachments) {

    /** @var \TYPO3\CMS\Fluid\View\StandaloneView $emailView */
    $emailView = $this->objectManager->get('TYPO3\\CMS\\Fluid\\View\\StandaloneView');

    $extbaseFrameworkConfiguration = $this->configurationManager->getConfiguration(\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Configuration\ConfigurationManagerInterface::CONFIGURATION_TYPE_FRAMEWORK);
    if(empty($extbaseFrameworkConfiguration['view']['templateRootPath'])){
        $extbaseFrameworkConfiguration['view']['templateRootPath'] = $extbaseFrameworkConfiguration['view']['templateRootPaths'][0];    
    }
    $templateRootPath = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::getFileAbsFileName($extbaseFrameworkConfiguration['view']['templateRootPath']);
    //DebuggerUtility::var_dump($templateRootPath);exit;
    $templatePathAndFilename = $templateRootPath . 'EmailTemplate/' . $templateName . '.html';
    $emailView->setTemplatePathAndFilename($templatePathAndFilename);
    $emailView->assignMultiple($variables); // assign Fluid variable
    $emailBody = $emailView->render();

    /** @var $message \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Mail\MailMessage */
    $message = $this->objectManager->get('TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Mail\\MailMessage');
    $message->setTo($recipient)
          ->setFrom($sender)
          ->setSubject($subject);

    // Possible attachments here
    /*if (count($attachments)) {
        foreach ($attachments as $file => $name) {
            if (file_exists($file)) {
                if (trim($name)) {
                    $message->attach(\Swift_Attachment::fromPath($file)->setFilename($name));
                } else {
                    $message->attach(Swift_Attachment::fromPath($file));
                }
            }
        }
    }*/

    // Plain text example
    //$message->setBody($emailBody, 'text/plain');

    // HTML Email
    $message->setBody($emailBody, 'text/html');

    $message->send();
    return $message->isSent();
}
```

Call from your action:

```
$isSend = $this->sendTemplateEmail(
    array($email => $user['title'].$user['first_name'].' '.$user['last_name']), // email TO $value['email']
    array($fromEmail => $fromName), // email From
    $subject, // Subject
    'YourEmailTemplateName', // Template name
    array('user' => $user) // Fluid variable
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created a helper class, which can be call from any extension with any template!

```
/**
 * Container class for mails
 * @package 
 */
class Mailer
{

/**
 * @param ControllerContext $context the controller, which calls this method
 * @param string $templatePath the path for the mail template like '/Resources/Private/Templates/.../'
 * @param string $templateName the name of the mail template without .html
 * @param array $assignArray the array with assign values for the template
 * @param string $sendTo the receiver address
 * @param string $sendFrom the sender address
 * @param string $subject the mail subject
 */
public static function sendMail(ControllerContext $context, $templatePath, $templateName, $assignArray, $sendTo, $sendFrom, $subject){

    if($context->objectManager == null){
        $context->objectManager = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance('TYPO3\\CMS\\Extbase\\Object\\ObjectManager');
    }

    $directoryName = '<</var/www/typo3/home/of/extensions/ext/>>' . strtolower($context->getRequest()->getControllerExtensionName());

    // Mail erstellen
    $templateName = $templateName;

    /** @var $emailView StandaloneView  */
    /** @noinspection PhpMethodParametersCountMismatchInspection */
    $emailView = $context->objectManager->get(\TYPO3\CMS\Fluid\View\StandaloneView::class, $context->contentObject);

    $emailView->setLayoutRootPaths(array($directoryName . '/Resources/Private/Layouts/'));

    $emailView->setPartialRootPaths(array($directoryName . '/Resources/Private/Partials/'));

    $templateRootPath = $directoryName . $templatePath;

    $templatePathAndFilename = $templateRootPath . $templateName . '.html';
    $emailView->getRequest()->setControllerExtensionName($context->getRequest()->getControllerExtensionName());
    $emailView->setTemplatePathAndFilename($templatePathAndFilename);

    $emailView->assignMultiple($assignArray);

    $emailBody = $emailView->render();

    /** @var $message MailMessage */
    $message = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance('TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Mail\\MailMessage');

    $message->setTo(
        $sendTo
    )->setFrom(
        $sendFrom
    )->setSubject(
        $subject
    );

    $message->setBody($emailBody, 'text/html');
    $message->send();
}
}
```

Please change the placeholder "/var/www/typo3/home/of/extensions/ext/" to your extensions home directory like "/var/www/typo3/typo3conf/ext/"!

Now you can call this class from a controller like this:

```
Mailer::sendMail($this->getControllerContext(), '/Resources/Private/Templates/<<SubFolders>>/', '<<Name of your Template>>', array(
        'name' => $value,
        'name2' => $value2,
        'name3' => $value3,
        ....
    ), 'test@test.de', 'no-replay@test.de', 'Subject');
```

This example works for Typo3 7.6.x to 8.x.x. Feel free to use it!

Comment: dirname(dirname(dirname(dirname(__FILE__)))) ?

Comment: This returns the absolute path to the Extension folder like `/var/www/typo3conf/ext` In my extension this class is situated under **Classes/Util**. If this class under **Classes** you need to write `dirname(dirname(dirname(FILE)))`. I will update of the code!